# Fixest and Standardized Coefficients from Easystats in R

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, modelsummary, fixest

I was wondering what would be the best way to calculate and present standardized coefficients using `fixest`. Here is what I tried using `easystats`

```
  library(parameters)
  library(effectsize)
  library(fixest)
  
  m <- lm(rating ~ complaints, data = attitude) 
  standardize_parameters(m, method="basic")# works

  m <- feols(rating ~ complaints, data = attitude) 
standardize_parameters(m, method="basic")# Error in stats::model.frame(model)[[1]] : subscript out of bounds
```

I also tried the `modelsummary` approach, but it shows unstandardized coefficients with no error.

```
   
   library(parameters)
   library(effectsize)
   
   m <- lm(rating ~ complaints, data = attitude)
   
   modelsummary(m, standardize="refit") # works, coeffs are different

   m <- feols(rating ~ complaints, data = attitude)

   modelsummary(m, standardize="refit")# doesn't work, coeffs are the same
```

Any insight or advice on how to elegantly and easily pull standardized coefficients out of `fixest` estimation results would be greatly appreciated. My goal is to replicate the venerable to use `listcoef` package in Stata. Many thanks to the authors of the packages mentioned in this post!

Edit: ``` > packageVersion("modelsummary")
[1] ‘1.1.0.9000’

Comment: Is `attitude` included in one of those packages? If not, run `dput(attitude)` and paste the output into your question. Typically it is best practice here to provide a reproducible dataset with your question, otherwise it is difficult for people to answer.

Comment: Yeah, I know. It's part of these packages. This is the example in https://easystats.github.io/parameters/articles/standardize_parameters_effsize.html which modelsummary uses.

Answer (score 1):

One potential solution is to just manually calculate the standardized coefficients yourself, as [detailed here][1]. As an example, below I scale your predictor and outcome, then calculate the standardized beta coefficient of the only predictor in your model.

```
#### Scale Predictor and Outcome ####
scale.x <- sd(attitude$complaints)
scale.y <- sd(attitude$rating)

#### Obtain Standardized Coefficients ####
sb <- coef(m)[2] * scale.x / scale.y
sb
```

Which gives you this (you can ignore the column name, as it is just borrowing it from the original `coef` vector):

```
complaints 
 0.8254176
```

[1]: https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/mathematics/standardized-regression-coefficient#:~:text=The%20standardized%20regression%20coefficient%2C%20found,one%20of%20its%20standardized%20units%20(

Comment: Thank you, Shawn! If there is no other way, the basic approach will have to suffice. I should have expressed myself clearer in my original post. I was looking to build a pipeline using  methods built in the mentioned packages especially given that `fixest` is great for my field,  `easystats` offers several advanced ways to standardize coeffs and `modelsummary` can present all of the standardized coefficients in a polished way. I also wondered if i found a bug or a way to help improve already excellent packages even more.

Comment: I tried it with the `iris` data and had a similar problem even with multiple predictors. Seems to be a bug. You could possibly file an issue with on Github with either the `fixest` authors (to tell them the limitations of getting betas) or the `modelsummary`/`standardized_parameters` authors (informing them that it doesn't seem to work on `fixest` objects.